# Merging 4 separate subplots in 1 figure having 4 subplots

Tags: matlab, plot

I have 4 different figures. Each figure contains 2 subplots (2 rows and 1 column)

The figures can be generated using the following code.

```
y = [2 2 3; 2 5 6; 2 8 9; 2 11 12];

for i = 1 : 4
    figure(i)
    subplot(2,1,1)
    bar(y)
    subplot(2,1,2)
    bar(y)
end
```

Having these 4 figures, is it possible to combine them in 1 figure?

the solution provided does not work with this other example where I create the figure using [barwitherr](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30639-bar-chart-with-error-bars/content/barwitherr.m)..why?

```
for i = 1 : 4
    figure(i)
    subplot(2,1,1)
    barwitherr([1 2 3 4;1 2 1 2], [5 6 7 8;1 2 3 4])
    subplot(2,1,2)
    barwitherr([1 2 3 4;1 2 1 2], [5 6 7 8;1 2 3 4])
end
for i = 1:4
    figure(i);
    ax = gca;
    f = get(ax, 'children');

    figure(5);
    s = subplot(2, 2, i);
    copyobj(f, s);
end
```

Comment: merging while creating or afterwards?

Comment: I'm confused, there are 8 subplots here.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what you want but is very extensible. You can loop through each of the original 4 figures and get handles for each of the `subplot`s within it. Once the figure we are interested in using `figure(i)` is the current `gcf` object we can get a handle to each of the subplot elements with `s = subplot(2, 1, i)` providing we know the structure of the subplots and `i` is the subplot we are interested in.

We can then we use [`copyobj()`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/copyobj.html) and [`allchild()`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/allchild.html) to copy over each of the subplots to a new subplot in the new figure

```
copyobj(allchild(h), s)
```

[`allchild()`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/allchild.html) copies over all of the information in [`barwitherr()`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30639-bar-chart-with-error-bars/content/barwitherr.m) that is left out from the code you've copied from a previous edit of my answer to your question.

If we put all this together we can produce the full code as

```
for i = 1:4
    figure(5);

    n = i + (i - 1);

    s1 = subplot(4, 2, n);
    s2 = subplot(4, 2, n+1);

    h = figure(i);
    hs1 = subplot(2, 1, 1);
    hs2 = subplot(2, 1, 2);

    copyobj(allchild(hs1), s1)
    copyobj(allchild(hs2), s2)
end
```

`n = i + (i - 1);` is used to replicate the original ordering. The output produced by this is

[image: Output]

Comment: Hi, I already have the 4 figures having the 2 subplots and I want to merge the 4 figures in a figure having 4 subplots

Comment: @IKavanagh He doesn't need help in creating the plots correctly, as your answer explains, he needs help in merging already existing plots.

Comment: @thewaywewalk So he wants to take 4 separate figures each with 2 subplots and merge them into 1 figure with 4 subplots?

Comment: Unfortunately this only copies one of the two bar plots into the new subplot, had the same issue.

Comment: @lKavanagh I don't know, this is just how I got it, cause otherwise you lose one axis.

Comment: correct. 4 subplots, in each subplot there should be an exact copy of the orgininal figure (that had 2 subplots)

Comment: @gabboshow Maybe not exactly how you want it, but the above should do what I think you are looking for.

Comment: @IKavanagh thanks a lot for all your efforts, but still it is not good unless I can add a different yaxes for the right plot. The problem is that in my case the "scale" for the 2 plots is different... so the bars in the right sided plots would be barely visible... any idea how to fix this other issue? Since I am using barwitherror I do not know how to add another yaxes (I dont know whether is possible=

Comment: @gabboshow If I understand you correctly that is a different issue and is related to your use of `barwitherror()`. You would probably be better off asking a different question about that. The short answer is you can create plots with separate `y` axes.